# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'urljoin'

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I  have been working on a crawler using BeautifulSoup in pyhton2.7 and I came across this error:

**AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'urljoin**`

It is actually in the line:

`first_link = urlparse.urljoin('https://en.wikipedia.org/', article_link)`

I've imported the urljoin using urlparse

`from urlparse import urljoin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You imported two things:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
from urlparse import urljoin
```

The name `urlparse` is thus bound to a function, not the module. Just use `urljoin` as a global, not as an attribute:

```
first_link = urljoin('https://en.wikipedia.org/', article_link)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am running **urlparse 1.1.1** on **Python 2.7.18** and had issues with urljoin. From my understanding it is no longer supported, however I was able to accomplish extracting each URL correctly with this method. Hopefully this can help anyone having similar issues

**Before parse extracted links:**

```
/intl/en/ads/
https://google.com/intl/en/ads/
/services/
https://google.com/services/
/intl/en/about.html
```

**After parse extracted links**

```
https://google.com/intl/en/ads/
https://google.com/services/
https://google.com/intl/en/about.html
https://google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/
https://google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/
```

**Code To extract and join links (terminal script on linux):**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import re
import urlparse


target_url = raw_input("Enter the target url\n>")


class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'


def request(url):
    try:
        return requests.get("http://" + url)
        print(get_response)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        pass


def extract_links_from(url):
    response = request(str(target_url))
    return re.findall('(?:href=")(.*?)"',response.content)


def urljoin(href_links):
    for link in href_links:

        if "https://" + target_url not in link and "https://" in link:
            print(bcolors.WARNING + link + bcolors.ENDC)
        elif "https://www." + target_url not in link:
            print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "https://" + target_url + link + bcolors.ENDC)
        else:
            print(bcolors.OKBLUE + link + bcolors.ENDC)


href_links = extract_links_from(target_url)
urljoin(href_links)
```